# Problema con credenciales para server ftp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

Tengo problemas para acceder a mi servidor **ftp** desde Internet.  ingreso la dirección y cuando me aparece el login ingresos el usuario y la clave pero me arroja mensaje de que las credenciales están malas,  cuando ingreso en mi red local con las mimas credenciales funcioná todo bien, no entiendo que problema podría ser.

Sistema operativo **ubuntu 18** , servidor ftp **proftpd**.

Comment: ¿Cómo conectas con tu servidor desde fuera de tu red local?

Comment: ftp://111.111.111.111:21   o  ftp://111.111.111.111   en el navegador web la ip es de ejemplo

Comment: Entiendo que tienes en tu ruter un NAT bien hecho, de lo contrario, estás entrando en el FTP del router y no en el de tu ordenador. Luego el usuario que especificas no será correcto.

Comment: en el router hice el portfowarding al servidor ftp

Answer (score 0):

En [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/) se puede limitar el acceso al servidor en función de la dirección ip desde la que se accede.  La limitación se realiza mediante la directiva `<Limit LOGIN>`.

Es posible que tengas una configuración similar a ésta en tu archivo de configuración:

```
 <Limit LOGIN>
    # These are trusted addresses
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

    # Everyone else is denied
    DenyAll
  </Limit>
```

Si te fijas, con `Allow from` permitimos accesos desde la ip local 127.0.0.1 y denegamos el reto de accesos con `DenyAll`.

Eliminando el `DenyAll` no deberías tener problemas ;-)

Comment: gracias por responder , lamentablemente no encuentro ninguna linea que tenga esa configuracion al algo similar revise los archivos proftpd.conf y el tls.conf

Comment: Vendría bien que subieras la configuración de proftpd y el log de cuenda conectas, a ver si damos con el problema.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e92f4bfdd0daf1c6ebf8fdfccd00c839      parte1.      la configuracion de proftpd    

Parte dos https://gyazo.com/1e361f31c3f45b86076ac483231dd65e